# How to access to the document folder in every pc with visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio

I have a problem and i really need to solve it, i will make a simple example to relize it. Example, a pc has user name is ABC and the path to its document folder is "C:\Users\ABC\Documents" and the path to another pc is "C:\Users\DEF\Documents". I am coding a program that it will make text file in the document folder, but i don't know how to make it can search automatically the right path to the document folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/14tx8hby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
using System;

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("GetFolderPath: {0}", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
    }
}
```